# What are the benefits of building react app with (NodeJs) over (Without Nodejs)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

What are the benefits of building react app with (**NodeJs**) over (**Without Nodejs**) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Slightly easier integration due to there being plenty of resources on how to do it, I guess. But I don't think the backend really matters that much. At least, not more than it matters to any other application, so the case for Node.js or against will hold up with any other backend and any other front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several advantages with using nodejs assuming you are referring to using nodejs to work with bundlers like webpack etc.

1. faster development with features like webpack devserver.
2. modern language constructs. with the kind of plugin ecosystem we are free to use modern language constructs without worrying about browser support. It may be true to some extent for embedding babel and other scripts but not very easy to manage after a stage
3. helpful in writing unit tests. as the testing config can share most of the development configurations.
4. features like instrumentation for code coverage can be easily done with minimal configurations
5. lot of processes can be automated. ex: localization etc.

A lot of things becomes easy and maintainable

Comment: That's really helpful.. Thanks @Aditya